# Starling / ActionScript 3 signaling events up to Main

Tags: event-handling, program-entry-point, starling-framework, actionscript-3

Hi I have a little design Issue with Starling/ActionScript 3.

What I want to do is simple

```
 dispatchEvent( new flash.events.Event("CloseApp",true)); //send closing bubble events
```

while i have following methods in Main.as (main extends flash.display.Sprite)

```
 public Main():void //constructor
 {
     addEventListener( "CloseApp" , onCloseApp);
     _starling = new Starling(Game, stage); //everythings work ok
     _starling.start(); //nice 3d stuff and interactive menu ok.
 }

 //closing event handling: close the APP
 public function onCloseApp( e:flash.events.Event): void
 {
     NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
 }
```

seems there's no way to send events to "Main" while all other classes are correctly catching events. basically the "exit" button is the only thing that does not work in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event will only travel up to your Game instance. I think it should be the _starling.root

so based on what I see you should call _starling.root.addEventListener("CloseApp", onCloseApp);

BTW, if your button is a Starling display object it should dispatch a starling Event, not a flash one. You can use the newly created `dispatchEventWith('CloseApp')`

and lastly I recommend you change the callback signature to  `public function onCloseApp( e:Object):void` to prevent event class collisions.

[EDIT]
here is how I would handle your case. Provided you use starling >1.2 it should work :

1. I would change Main like this :

   ```
   public static const EVT_CLOSEAPP:String = 'close app';
   public Main():void //constructor
   {
     _starling = new Starling(Game, stage); //everythings work ok
     _starling.start(); //nice 3d stuff and interactive menu ok.
     _starling.addEventListener(EVT_CLOSEAPP , onCloseApp);
   }
   //closing event handling: close the APP
   public function onCloseApp( e:Object): void
   {
     NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
   }
   ```
2. then, in whatever class you are creating your close butto

   ```
   //... i assume your button is in a variable btn
   btn.addEventListener(Event:TRIGGER, onCloseBtn);//this is starling.event.Event
   //...
   protected function onCloseBtn(_e:Event)
   {
     Starling.current.dispatchEventWith(Main.EVT_CLOSEAPP);
   }
   ```

Comment: oh ok. I have questions : 
* Do you absolutely need the onClose code to be in your Main class?
* are you using a debug flash player? the code you showed should throw errors because of the flash.events/starling.events confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Starling [has its own version of event dispatching](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/why-another-eventdispatcher-and-event-classes).

What should work is

1. Dispatch a `starling.events.Event` instead of a `flash.events.Event`
2. Add a listener directly on the `_starling` or `_starling.stage` object.

Comment: please post some working simple example, I already tried that and didn't worked ( i tried both ways). I tried also to make a simple Application just with the "Exit" button, but didn't worked.. there's a flaw somewhere. I'm sure but didn't find it :(

Comment: sorry don't work. I'm starting thinking that's a bug of Starling/AS3

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expiriance developer with starling but I have similar problem and I solved it by adding a static var and call methods from there. In your case you can use something like this:

in your Game class add: 
    public static var mainDoc: MovieClip;

in your main method add: 
    Game.mainDoc = this;

then in your Game class instead of rising an events you can call a method mainDoc.onCloseApp()

also you can try
_starling.addEventListener or _starling.stage.addEventListener as say Antoine Lassauzay

Comment: well yes actually mi solution is closing the app with NativeApplication.exit() without sending any message.. that's a design break so kind of ugly code but works..

Answer (score 0):

@Boris already explained that.

I have resolved problem.

Example I made File from flash.filesystem.File in App.as (My application was created by Moonshine) and TextInput from feathers.controls.TextInput; in Main.as with Starling's events

Like that:

```
package
{
    import Main;
    import feathers.utils.ScreenDensityScaleFactorManager;

    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageOrientation;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display3D.Context3DProfile;
    import flash.display3D.Context3DRenderMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.system.Capabilities;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import starling.core.Starling;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;


    [SWF(width="640",height="480",frameRate="60",backgroundColor="#4a4137")]
    public class NewFeathersSDKDesktopProject extends Sprite
    {
        public function NewFeathersSDKDesktopProject()
        {
            if(this.stage)
            {
                this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
                this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            }
            this.mouseEnabled = this.mouseChildren = false;
            this.showLaunchImage();
            this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderInfo_completeHandler);
        }

        private var _starling:Starling;
        private var _scaler:ScreenDensityScaleFactorManager;
        private var _launchImage:Loader;
        private var _savedAutoOrients:Boolean;

        ...

        private function loaderInfo_completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            Starling.multitouchEnabled = true;
            this._starling = new Starling(Main, this.stage, null, null, Context3DRenderMode.AUTO, Context3DProfile.BASELINE);
            this._starling.supportHighResolutions = true;
            this._starling.skipUnchangedFrames = true;
            this._starling.start();
            if(this._launchImage)
            {
                this._starling.addEventListener("rootCreated", starling_rootCreatedHandler);
            }

            this._scaler = new ScreenDensityScaleFactorManager(this._starling);
            this.stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, stage_deactivateHandler, false, 0, true);

            // dispatch from Main.as dispatchEventWith();
            this._starling.addEventListener("trigger", button_triggeredHandler)
        }

        ...
        
        private var fileopen:File;
        public function button_triggeredHandler(event:Object):void
        {
            fileopen = new File();
            var txtFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Text", "*.as;*.css;*.html;*.txt;*.xml");
            try 
            {
                fileopen.browseForOpen("Open", [txtFilter]);
                fileopen.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected)
            }
            catch (error:Error)
            {
                trace("Failed:", error.message);
            }
        }
        
        public function fileSelected(event:Event):void
        {
            Main.textinput.text = fileopen.nativePath;
        }

    }
}
```

And Main.as

```
package
{
    import feathers.controls.Button;
    import feathers.controls.TextCallout;
    import feathers.themes.MetalWorksDesktopTheme;

    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.core.Starling;
    import starling.events.Event;
    import feathers.core.Application;
    import feathers.controls.TextInput;

    public class Main extends Application
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            new MetalWorksDesktopTheme();
            super();

            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        protected var button:Button;
        public static  var textinput:TextInput;

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

            this.button = new Button();
            this.button.label = "Choose";
                        
            textinput = new TextInput();

            //an event that tells us when the user has tapped the button.
            this.button.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, button_triggeredHandler);

            this.addChild(this.button);
            this.addChild(textinput);

            this.button.x = this.button.y = 10;
            textinput.x = 90;
            textinput.y = 10;
            textinput.width = 400;
        }
        
        private function button_triggeredHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            // Call to Application's class ( App or created by Moonshine IDE )
            Starling.current.dispatchEventWith("trigger");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you know how do you get like your air app works fine like charm :D

PS: I am really surprised why do Actionscript 3 developers continue until now?
I thought Flash Player is died. Since I exchange to Net developer - I don't expect there AS3 developers skip with Harman Air. I checked news - I am shocking why does company Harman continue and works hardly. I don't understand why does Harman release Linux with Commincial version :(. And successor Moonshine IDE. I find okay. but I wish dark mode on Moonshine IDE. Becuase my eyes are sensitive.